# Offsetting scrollTop

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, offset

I have the following snippet

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#menu').offset().top}, 'slow');
```

On click of a link I would like the browser to display from *near* the top of the #menu div. I would like it display just few pixels lines before the menu.

How can I achieve this?

I have added paddingTop:5 to offset() but this is not the desired result.

Comment: ... You were thinking too far. Why not just add 5 to `$('#menu').offset().top`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just subtract whatever amount you want from `$('#menu').offset().top`:

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#menu').offset().top - 5 // or 10
}, 'slow');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qVWuv/

Answer (score 0):

This code has fixed it.

```
$(function() {
      $('a').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(0) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('#content').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top - 15
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```